# Retrieving a list of objects with a SOAP wcf webservice

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap, dotnetopenauth

I am currently in the process of building a webservice that is authenticated via the DotNetOpenAuth library. To this end, I have created two sites on an IIS7 server, one with the consumer, the other with the provider and the actual webservice (incidentally I'm currently debugging the consumer project locally, but eventually I'll switch to the consumer project on the seperate IIS7 site).

The implementation of each project seperately works like a charm, however, while tying it all together I came across an issue.

The webservice is called from the consumer, and returns a `List<TimeTable>` (TimeTable being a class I wrote myself). However, whenever I test my code the webservice works fine, producing a list of about 300 items, but when it is received by the consumer the list suddenly has a count of 0.

I believe this might be due to the fact that the webservice and consumer are seperate projects; the consumer project doesn't "know" the TimeTable class (since it only exists in the service provider project), so in the consumer I try using a `List<object>` to store the `List<TimeTable>` in, which apparently doesn't work. However I don't know what I should be using instead.

Thoughts?

EDIT: as requested, I added the most important methods from the consumer and provider. Note that most of these are pretty much identical to the DotNetOpenAuth examples- retrieving a string, or a 'List' in this manner works perfectly.

**Methods in consumer**
*SampleWcf.aspx.cs*

```
protected void retrieveTimeTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {                
         List<object> timeTables = CallService(client => client.retrieveTimeTable("1", "52"));
         this.retrieveTimeTableLabel.Text = timeTables.Count.ToString();
     }
     catch (SecurityAccessDeniedException)
     { this.retrieveTimeTableLabel.Text = "Access denied!"; }}

private T CallService<T>(Func<DataApiClient, T> predicate) 
{
    DataApiClient client = new DataApiClient();
    var serviceEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(client.Endpoint.Address.Uri, HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.PostRequest);
    var accessToken = Session["WcfAccessToken"] as string;
    if (accessToken == null) 
    { throw new InvalidOperationException("No access token!"); }
    WebConsumer consumer = this.CreateConsumer();
    WebRequest httpRequest = consumer.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(serviceEndpoint, accessToken);
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpDetails = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpDetails.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = httpRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];
    using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel)) {
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpDetails;
          return predicate(client); }}
```

*in class DataApiClient*

```
public List<string> getList()
{ return base.Channel.getList(); }
```

**Methods in provider**
*in class DataApi.cs*

```
public List<TimeTable> retrieveTimeTable(string weekVan, string weekTot)
{
    TimeTableWebService ttws = new TimeTableWebService();
    List<TimeTable> results = ttws.getTimeTable(weekVan, weekTot);

    StringBuilder fbr = new StringBuilder();
    fbr.AppendLine("New log created on: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    fbr.AppendLine("Number of results: " + results.Count);

    using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"D:\oauthSiteTest\log9.txt"))
    { outfile.Write(fbr.ToString()); }

    return results; }
```

Comment: Can you show some code of how these methods are implemented on the consumer and the provider?  When you generate the service client it should generate unknown types like `TimeTable` automatically.

Comment: Certainly! Also, TimeTable is generated properly in my .wsdl file- I can see its definition in a .xsd file as normal. Earlier I hosted the webservice separately on IIS7 (using soapUI to retrieve data rather than doing it via DotNetOpenAuth's consumer/SP), and the .xsd file generated by *that* webservice is identical to the new, protected webservice.